# Cannot read property 'propertyName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I'm working on a project in react-native where I have troubles of accessing an element inside an object array by passing it as a prop where I want it to be used. Requirement is to get the name property out and set it to a text inside a flatlist.

The structure of my object array as follow.

```
[
 { 
  "media1":[ 
            {"name":"Lynn"},
            {"name":"Michelle"},
            {"name":"Carter"}
           ]
 },
 { 
  "media2":[ 
            {"price":"23"},
            {"price":"76"},
            {"price":"39"}

           ]
 }
]
```

This is how is pass this object array as a prop where I want it to be used

```
return (
        <View>
           <AlbumDetail data = {this.state.allData}/>
        </View>
    );
```

This is where I want it to be used

```
 const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
 return (

 <View>
    {console.log(props.data[0])} //Working
    {console.log(props.data[0].media1[0].name)} //Not working

    // Requirement as bellow
    <Text>{wants to set the "name" here}</Text> 
    <Text>{wants to set the "price" here}</Text> 
 </View>   
);
};
```

How can I achieve this ??

Comment: There are two places where you can get this error. Either `data[0]` is `undefined` or `media`[0]1 is. Use Chrome Developer tools to determine which it is.

Comment: it saysa cannot read the property "media"  of undefined. why is that and what should i do

Comment: `props.data` isn't what you expect it to be. Either you are not passing it in correctly or you are modifying the state of the parent component which in turn modifies the props of the `AlbumDetail`.

Comment: Please add the result of console.log(props.data[0]) to your question.

Comment: the response is => {media1: Array(18)}
this has 18 objects in the form of [{"name":"john"}, {"name":"paul"},.........]

Comment: The error says that it cannot read media of undefined, so data[0] should be undefined at the second call and the code you are showing tries to use media1, while the error message says media is not found, so the error message contradicts your descirption, therefore either you are not showing the real code (for the sake of simplicity, for instance) or the error occurs at another place. I do not have enough details about your problem to give you a solution.

Comment: try to put some string to the log, just to make sure that the error comes from that line

Answer (score -1):

You might want to place two missing comma's.
One after:

```
{"name":"Michelle"}
```

And one after

```
{"price":"76"}
```

Comment: In CodeSandBox I had to add props as an extra property:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n3076ron7j

Answer (score -1):

1. AlbumDetail has no way to know it has a property called data. You need to write AlbumDetail function as a React.Component class.
2. You are passing a JSON object into AlbumDetail, you need to call JSON.parse(data) before use it. UPDATE: `.then(resp => resp.json())` is used to parse json.
3. Place console.log before return. The object you returned should be pure JSX components.

The code below should solve your problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const url =
  'http://purelight-prod.appspot.com/api/user/v2/browse/homescreendata';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: undefined,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(respJson => {
        this.setState({
          data: respJson,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TestView data={this.state.data} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class TestView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    !!this.props.data && console.log(console.log(data[0].healer[0].healerid));
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**:

Use `componentDidMount()`, because we like to display something (loading icon, etc), and then update the View when data arrived.

This is an async task. The data has to be held until it arrived. I use `!!this.props.data && ...`, so it only displays when it is not undefined.

Since the API response is a relatively big package, it will be much easier to work with, if you use TypeScript and create an object class to parse it.

I don't think the API helper package provides correct response in your code.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting?

Comment: it says even props is undefined in this way sir.

Comment: Try this <View>{ AlbumDetail(this.state.allData) }</View> with your function but move console.log before return. Have you import react and react-native in your file?

Comment: Any git link, so I could take a look the full file?

Comment: Just updated the correct demo of using react component, console.log and API call.

Comment: I can console.log the data array, my requirement is to accesses the lowest level key inside an object... eg:- console.log(this.props.data[0].healer)

Comment: `console.log(data[0].healer[0].healerid)` will print the 1st healerid which is 5. Similar idea, the keys can be access by **for (let key in data[0].healer[0]) { console.log(key); }**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164379/discussion-between-danu-and-leekinpajama).

Comment: In your case, this API response will be much easier to deal with if using **TypeScript**. I prefer to loop through each layer to get all keys outside React-Native, and then create `interface` to map the data. **(Debug in react native is too slow)**

Comment: hi can u please remove the api call @LeeklnPajama

Comment: What do you mean "remove the api call"? From where?

Comment: const url =
  'http://purelight-prod.appspot.com/api/user/v2/browse/homescreendat'